# How can i install yeoman command line tool on ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS?

Tags: asp.net-core, ubuntu, npm, yeoman, ubuntu-20.04

I tried installing yeoman command line tool in Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS for ASP.NET Core web application development. After typing
`npm install -g yo` in terminal, i got an error.

Description of error is provided below.

````
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated cross-spawn-async@2.2.5: cross-spawn no longer requires a build toolchain, use it instead
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib']
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/shashankshekhar/.npm/_logs/2020-12-21T11_02_14_859Z-debug.log```
````

Comment: sudo npm install -g yo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue of `EACCES` errors on global module installation is so common that `npm` has [an entire web page dedicated to solving just this issue](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally).

Since you are installing yeoman, I imagine this is a development machine. In that case, your best bet is likely to install `node`/`npm` with a package manager like [`nvm`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm).

One thing you *don't* want to do but that people will often suggest is running the `npm` command with `sudo`. People recommend this because it's *easy*. But if you do that, all the lifecycle scripts (e.g., `postinstall`) of the dependencies of whatever you are installing will also be run as `root`. That's potentially a *lot* of untrusted code running as `root`.